# Подскажите библиотеку для создания pdf

Tags: pdf, php

Подскажите библиотеку для создания pdf. Требуется малое:

1. Вставка картинки
2. Вставка текста кириллицы
3. Поддержка, адекватная, встраивания шрифтов и использования именно их для пункта 2
4. Примечание к 3 пункту: otf и на лету при создании документа

Что попробовал:

1. FPDF - не подходит из за отсутствия встраивания шрифтов на лету. Готовить файлы с метриками я не буду, так как это, имхо, костыль!
2. TCPDF - аналогично
3. PDFLib - замечательный претендент. Шрифты встраиваются успешно, но не хватило знаний научить библиотеку кириллице (тесты провожу на винде 32)
4. zend овская байда с родни fpdf - имеет те же проблемы. Но, буду честен, не тестил достаточно хорошо.

Я склоняюсь к 3му пункту - научите меня (ссылкой на хорошую статью про настройку на работу с кириллицей, причем чтобы статья была проверена Вашим опытом) или подскажите мне дорогу в правильном направлении.

П.С.: проект пока использует кириллицу и, понятно, что поддерживает латиницу. Я не силен в теории, поэтому сори за не компетентность: Хочется научить без серверных надстроек научить работать проект с любыми языками. Например: японские иероглифы и т.д.

Comment: Мде... Японские иероглифы и кириллица? о_О

Comment: @AlexWindHope, может это генератор PDFок c заданиями для изучения японского )

Comment: Это редактор визиток) Просто ориентируюсь на поддержку любого языка. Для примера и привел японский.После отрисовки визитки, мне надо ее в pdf загнать. Соответственно и шрифты подцепить и картинку на бекграунд поставить, возможно логотипчики, возможно спец. символы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download), рекомендую

Comment: Сейчас затестим!) Спасибо.

Comment: Не смотря на то, что многое надо ему давать в html, все мои потребности удовлетворены на ура! Спасибо за ссылку. Даже если что-то не подойдет, открытость позволяет допилить под себя!

Comment: Аккуратнее с картинками. Я как-то наткнулся на беду: нужно было преобразовать простенькую HTML-разметку с картинками в PDF, так mpdf вылетал при больших количествах картинок × их размер. То есть, либа не может писать данные сразу в файл по мере их поступления, а хранит все в памяти. Из-за этого случался перерасход выделенных 256М на шаред хостинге.

Кстати, если кто-то знает, как можно включить потоковую запись в этой либе — поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: не знал об этой библиотеке... классная и удобная.

Answer (score 1):

PDFLib в бесплатной версии не поддерживает
utf-8. Если хочешь именно его, то приобретай платную версию.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Посмотрю в эту сторону, но, к сожалению, работодатель вкладывает только в зарплату работников(

Comment: Работодателю/клиенту обычно в таких случаях полезно сказать: "Разработка фичи `A` без данной библиотеки займет `n` дней, а с библиотекой будет `m` дней. Причем библиотеку мы сможем использовать еще и в проектах `B`, `C` и `D`", где `n >> m`.

Comment: Я фрилансер и цне оговорена заранее(

Answer (score 0):

Я в своем проекте использовал [domPdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)
Кирилица - [читаем здесь](http://www.zefo.ru/index.php/topic,1871.0.html)